# How to replace a drive in a btrfs filesystem with no spare drive slots?

Tags: 14.04, mount, raid, btrfs

I have a btrfs filesystem in RAID 1 on two drives of the same size. If one drive failed then I'd want to replace it with a new one. On the wiki [here](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices#Replacing_failed_devices) there is a description of how you can replace a failed drive. Since I only have two hard drive slots, it seems my best option would be to umount my filesystem, yank out the broken drive, mount the filesystem again in degraded mode, add in my new drive and then replace the removed one. This would mean the data would be inaccessible temporarily which is not ideal. Is there a better way to do this so that the data is always accessible but still only requiring two drives attached at any one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always convert the filesystem from RAID1 to single.

Then you will be able to delete a failed disk, then add a new one, then rebalance to RAID1 again.

But in this case you have a risk of the second disk failure while it is the only one.

It is not a good idea since balancing to single may choose a bad drive to move the data to.

So there is no perfect solution. You need either to connect a 3rd device to replace, or unmount the filesystem for a while.

Comment: I guess this would work but seems like a bit of a hack as I want to stay in RAID 1 but just make it degraded for a brief period. Yeah that's what I was just about to ask, is there any way to control this process to force the conversion to single to only use the working drive?

Comment: No, there is no way to choose a disk.

Comment: Wouldn't this work: `btrfs balance start -f -dconvert=single,devid=2 -mconvert=single,devid=2 /mnt` assuming that devid refers to the healthy disk and /mnt is the filesystem mount point? This came from [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1087787/linux-btrfs-convert-to-single-with-failed-drive)

Comment: I never used `devid`. It is a good idea.